# set the column code as foreign key on table with a reference to another table

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Wrc.png)I got a problem regarding my two table. The name of one table tblShoes and the other one is tblplayer. the problem is **I want to Set the column Code in table tblPLAYERS as FOREIGN KEY with a reference to table tblSHOES column code**. but I trying to insert my code in table tblPLAYER but it doesn't work can you help me and explain why please.
here is my two table.

> create table tbl_Shoe
>
> (
>
> code varchar not null primary key,
>      brand varchar not null,
>      model int not null,
>      size varchar not null
>
> );
>
> create table tbl_PLAYER
>
> (
>
> RosterNo int  primary key,
>        Name varchar ,
>        Position varchar,
>        Code varchar
>
> primary key (code),
>        foreign key (Code) references tblShoe (code)
>
> );

help me please! you are very big help for me. thanks a lot.
this is my code
[http.clickimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Wrc.png)

Comment: Do you just need the syntax for creating a foreign key?

Comment: What do you meant by * it doesn't work* ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @prdp the error when I'm try to execute the tblPLAYER like this 'Cannot add multiple PRIMARY KEY constraints to table 'tblPLAYER'."

Comment: Please remove useless Jargon like ´tbl´ in front of your names. Most objects seen are tables, so the redundancy reflects poorly on the designer. Instead, use the valuable naming convention to make it easy on those who develop and manage your code (ie Players_DIM, Players_FACT, Teams_Roster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key is a reference to another table. It is used to establish relationships between tables. For example, relationship between tbl_Shoe and tbl_PLAYER table. One  tbl_Shoe can have multiple codes. The Primary key of tbl_Shoe becomes foreign key of codes of another table which is the tbl_PLAYER.so here is my answer.

```
 create table tbl_Shoes
```

`Codes varchar (20) not null primary key,
     brand varchar(50) not null,
     model int not null,
    size varchar(10) not null
     );`

```
create table tbl_PLAYERS
```

`(
     RosterNo int  primary key,
     Name varchar(20) ,
     Position varchar(20),
     code varchar (20) not null,
      Codes varchar (20) not null constraint fk_code foreign key references tblShoes(Codes)
     );`

Answer (score 0):

When you define a foreign key, you're saying "hey database, guarantee that this value exists in the other table". In your case, you're saying that for whatever value you're putting in the `tblPlayer.Code` column, there needs to be a matching row that has the same value in `tblShoe`. For example, if I only have codes A, B, and C in tblShoe and I try to insert a row into `tblPlayer` with a code of D, it won't work.

Comment: thank you for answering both of you. so it sames to be the code of tblPLAYER and tblSHOES must be they same value

Comment: Specifically, the code has to exist in `tblShoes` before any rows in `tblPlayer` can reference it.